# How to set the position of an equation in LaTeX?

Tags: floats, equations

In normal equation I do not have any problem. However for long equation I need to use figure so that my equation appear more obviously. (Note: I am using two column paper style).

This is the equation style that I use:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{refstyle}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\title{\huge Single line equation in two column paper}

\maketitle

\section{First} \label{first}

\lipsum[1-6]

\begin{figure*}[t]
\normalsize
\begin{align} \label{eqn1}
Long_{eqn}^{1} &=  aaa aaa aaa aaa + aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa + aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa + aaa aaa aaa aaa \nonumber\\
&+ bbb bbb  bbb bbb  bbb bbb + bbb bbb  bbb bbb  bbb bbb  bbb bbb  bbb +bbb  bbb bbb  bbb bbb  bbb bbb  bbb +bbb  bbb bbb  bbb bbb \nonumber\\
&+ ccc ccc  ccc ccc  ccc ccc  +ccc ccc  ccc ccc  ccc ccc  ccc ccc+  ccc ccc  ccc ccc  ccc ccc + ccc ccc  ccc ccc  ccc ccc  ccc ccc .
\end{align}
\end{figure*}

\lipsum[2-5]

\section{Second} \label{second}

\lipsum[3-8]

\begin{figure*}[t]
\normalsize
\begin{align} \label{eqn2}
Long_{eqn}^{2} &=  aaa aaa aaa aaa + aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa + aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa + aaa aaa aaa aaa \nonumber\\
&+ bbb bbb  bbb bbb  bbb bbb + bbb bbb  bbb bbb  bbb bbb  bbb bbb  bbb +bbb  bbb bbb  bbb bbb  bbb bbb  bbb +bbb  bbb bbb  bbb bbb \nonumber\\
&+ ccc ccc  ccc ccc  ccc ccc  +ccc ccc  ccc ccc  ccc ccc  ccc ccc+  ccc ccc  ccc ccc  ccc ccc + ccc ccc  ccc ccc  ccc ccc  ccc ccc .
\end{align}
\end{figure*}

\lipsum[4-8]

\end{document}
```

My problem is that; I can't put this equation in its actual position. It will be either on the top or bottom of the next page. I want it to be in its normal position.

I have checked previous related questions, such as ([How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat)) and ([How to use the placement options [t], [h] with figures?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35125/how-to-use-the-placement-options-t-h-with-figures)), but non of them was useful to my case. Therefore, I preferred to ask this question.

Comment: If you don't want the equation to float about, then don't put it in a floating environment.  If you just want to give it some extra space, then you could use `\smallskip`, `\medskip` or `\bigskip` before it and/or after it.

Comment: Are you just trying to add space and rule around the equation?

Comment: @Thruston As the equation is too long, it will cover both columns completely. Therefore, I should use this representation style.

Comment: Ah multicolumns!  can you please post a proper MWE that shows the problem.

Comment: One [possible solution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149832/one-column-figure-in-a-two-column-document-goes-to-a-next-page)

Comment: [Another solution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28199/add-an-equation-at-the-bottom-of-a-two-column-article)

Comment: @Thruston I have amended the question.

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16429/equation-spanning-two-columns-in-ieeetran)?

Comment: @Thruston I have tried to follow the steps that mentioned in (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16429/equation-spanning-two-columns-in-ieeetran), but it is not work with me. I have an error message. Could you please check if it work with you? (I mean using the MWE that I provided).

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314257/time-travel-in-latex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a better solution would be to use the `cuted` package from the `sttools` bundle. It is dedicated to insert some material full-width in a twocolumn environment:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{refstyle}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cuted, nccmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength\stripsep{3pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}

\begin{document}

\title{\huge Single line equation in two column paper}

\maketitle

\section{First} \label{first}

\lipsum[1-6]
\begin{strip}
  \begin{align} \label{eqn1}
    Long_{eqn}¹ & = aaa aaa aaa aaa + aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa + aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa + aaa aaa aaa aaa \nonumber \\
                   & + bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb + bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb +bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb +bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb \nonumber \\
                   & + ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc +ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc+ ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc + ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc .
  \end{align}
\end{strip}
%
\lipsum[2-5]

\section{Second} \label{second}

\lipsum[3-8]
\begin{strip}
  \normalsize
  \begin{align} \label{eqn2}
    Long_{eqn}² & = aaa aaa aaa aaa + aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa + aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa + aaa aaa aaa aaa \nonumber \\
                   & + bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb + bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb +bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb +bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb \nonumber \\
                   & + ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc +ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc+ ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc + ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc .
  \end{align}
\end{strip}
\lipsum[4-8]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think the code that you provided is my own code without changes.

Comment: Oh! Sorry! Bad copy-paste. I'll change it at once.

Comment: It works perfectly.